# how to read Arabic input from cmd?

Tags: cmd

I want to ask if can read entered query in Arabic in cmd when running the program written in python ( my program accept query from user in cmd, it accepts the English input but doesn't accept the Arabic input )?

Comment: Please show the code which is not working as you expect. If you do not have the source code or cannot read it, please contact the application developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow unicode character support in `cmd` you need to set the code page for the language you are after.

This is done with

```
chcp CodePageNumber
```

I think arabic should be `chcp 708`

See more info here: http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html

And a list of code pages here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I am from Palestine and I have same error there is no c]code page number for Palestine what should I do